fields on the New Contact button
How do I control what fields are visible in the + New Contact pop up that appears when you create a New Contact from the drop down beside the Object name on the main navigation (tabs) or the New button on a Contact List view.

In general, the fields are controlled by the Page Layout that is assigned to the user's Profile for the selected Record Type (not available in all Editions), although note that Field Level Security can hide fields as well. It is also possible to use a standard button override if you want to create a custom interface that's unrelated to Page Layout. In other words, there's a lot of possible configuration options depending on what you're trying to do.
